# TextureBrush Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to place a watermark ontop of another image. This is my code:

```
var imgPhoto = Image.FromFile(filePath);
var grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(imgPhoto);

var point = new Point(imgPhoto.Width - imgWatermark.Width, imgPhoto.Height - imgWatermark.Height);

var brWatermark = new TextureBrush(imgWatermark, new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, imgWatermark.Width, imgWatermark.Height));

grPhoto.FillRectangle(brWatermark, new Rectangle(point, imgWatermark.Size));
imgPhoto.Save(outputFolder + @"\" + filename);
```

One problem occurs however, the TextureBrush throws an out of memory exception. I've searched around but I couldn't really find a good solution. As far as I can see nothing is disposed before TextureBrush tries to do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am willing to bet that the file at `filePath` is fairly large.

`OutOfMemoryException` usually happens when you have .NET heap fragmentation, so here you are probably trying to load a file which is larger than any available block of memory in the Runtime.

Try compressing your image file, or crop it to make it smaller if that is acceptable.

**EDIT** 
Try opening your file in an image editor such as MS Paint, or Paint.NET. Then re-save it.

If that doesn't work, try this (basically make sure your rectangle's bounds are inside the watermark image):
http://www.owenpellegrin.com/blog/net/out-of-memory-errors-with-gdi-texturebrush/

Comment: The images are about 800kb each, filePath is just a small string. I dont think this could be the problem. Compressing or cropping is not acceptable sadly.

Comment: Then it is `imgWatermark`.  What kind of file was `imgWatermark`, and how big was it?

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809098/windows-7-texturebrush-ctor-error

Comment: Found the problem, it was the rectangle not being in the correct place. To prevent the watermark from tiling on the wrong spot I had to use brWatermark.TranslateTransform(point.X, point.Y);

Answer (score 4):

Also, this can happen when the stream that the `Image` was loaded from has been disposed. Try to avoid disposing the image stream if you plan on creating a texture brush. For example, this would work:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("image.bmp");
System.Windows.Controls.Image image = null;
using (var stream = System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = System.Windows.Controls.Image.FromStream(stream);
    var brush = new System.Drawing.TextureBrush(image); // No issues
}
```

But doing almost the same thing with the mistake of disposing the stream would generate that exception.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("image.bmp");
System.Windows.Controls.Image image = null;
using (var stream = System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
{
     image = System.Windows.Controls.Image.FromStream(stream); 
}
var brush = new System.Drawing.TextureBrush(image); // Exception Thrown!
```

Comment: This answer just fixed my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (correctly identifies that the out of memory exception occurs because of the underlying stream disposal).

Answer (score 3):

Check the size of your bound area. In your case this will be **new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, imgWatermark.Width, imgWatermark.Height)**. I had the same "Out of memory" problem and the reason was that my bound area was bigger than my texture size.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `IDisposable` resources in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements in order to ensure proper disposal as soon as possible. Also don't expect to be able to do a `Image.FromFile` on files that are bigger than what can fit in memory.